# regular expression that can handle java exceptions

Tags: java, regex, log4j

I am trying to write a log parser for log4j.  I have a regular expression that works for normal messages but when it gets to a message that throws an exception it will only show whats on the first line and will not match the stack trace.

How would I write a regular expression that can handle Java exceptions spanning multiple lines?

Here is the current regex I am using in java:

```
^(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(.+)$
```

Here is a normal log msg:

```
2012-01-25 20:10:03,480 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler: nodeUpdate: example.com:1 clusterResources: memory: 1
```

Here is an example exception log msg:

```
2012-01-25 00:03:59,565 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode: Exception in doCheckpoint
java.io.IOException: Inconsistent checkpoint fields.
LV = -1 namespaceID = 1 cTime = 0 ; clusterId = CID-1 ; blockpoolId = BP-
Expecting respectively: -1; 1; 0; CID-1; BP-1
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.CheckpointSignature.validateStorageInfo(CheckpointSignature.java:111)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.doCheckpoint(SecondaryNameNode.java:510)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.doWork(SecondaryNameNode.java:381)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode$2.run(SecondaryNameNode.java:344)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:337)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1149)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.run(SecondaryNameNode.java:341)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a Java exception that you want to match? So us regex folk who aren't also java/log4j folk can help you out? :) The only recommendations I can make are to look into the 'DOTALL' regex flag (often 's') which lets `.` match all characters including `\n`, and the 'MULTILINE' regex flag (often 'm') which lets `^` and `$` match start/end of line as well as start/end of string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
(.*\\bERROR\\b.*)\\r?\\n(.*\\r?\\n)*(.*\\bat\\b.*)*(\\d{1,4}\\)\\r?\\n)
```

I'm making the assumption that you're reading your log file into a `CharSequence` and passing that to the pattern matcher in Java instead of reading the file line by line.